# What is wrong with my if condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I found the answer to this question on this site but i just want to understand why my solution wasn't working. The question asked to implement an difference function, which subtracts one list from another.

It should remove all values from list a, which are present in list b.

My Original Code :

```
function array_diff(array,num) {
  var results = [];

  array.forEach(function(ele, idx, array){
    if (num !== ele) {
      results.push(ele)
      console.log("a is now " + ele)
      console.log("b is " + num)
    } 
  })
  return results;
}
```

But everytime i feed it this argument array_diff([1,2,2],[2]), it returned the original array and i dont know why

Comment: Take a look at the source of Underscore or Lodash `_.difference`.

Answer (score 2):

You are using an array for `num` instead of a number.

```
array_diff([1, 2, 2], 2)
//                    ^
```

```js
function array_diff(array, num) {
    var results = [];

    array.forEach(function(ele, idx, array){
        if (num !== ele) {
            results.push(ele);
            console.log("a is now " + ele);
            console.log("b is " + num);
        } 
    });
    return results;
} 

console.log(array_diff([1, 2, 2], 2));
```

If the question is about using an array for `numbers`, then you could use [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) to check if the element is in the `numbers` array. You could use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) as well.

```js
function array_diff(array, numbers) {
    return array.filter(function(element) {
        return numbers.indexOf(element) === -1;
    });
} 

console.log(array_diff([1, 2, 2], [2]));
console.log(array_diff([1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7], [1, 3, 5, 7]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: OP is attempting to implement a difference function; the arguments should both still be arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You compared it with an array (num) which will always return false since your ele is an integer.

use this instead

```
array_diff([1,2,2], 2)
```

or if you want to change the function

```
function array_diff(array,num) {
  var results = [];

  array.forEach(function(ele, idx, array){
    if (num.indexOf(ele) === -1) {
      results.push(ele)
      console.log("a is now " + ele)
      console.log("b is " + num)
    } 
  })
  return results;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your comparaison is wrong, you should write :

```
if(num != ele)
```

and not

```
if(num !== ele)
```

Comment: oh that works even with an array as the num can you explain whats the difference?

Comment: !== compare type and value

Comment: != only compare value